# How can i do update table doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have this script for inserting the data:

```
echo "Update ";
$department = new Department();
$department->setNamedepartment($data ['nameDepartment']);
$department->setCodedepartment($data ['codeDepartment']);
$department->setIdfkgeographicalarea($data ['idFkGeographicalArea']);
$entityManager->persist($department);
$entityManager->flush();
```

how can I update my `$department` entity with only this call: `update($data,$id)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function update ($data, $id) use ($entityManager) {
    $departament = $entityManager->find('Your\EntityNamespace\Departament', $id);

    $department->setNamedepartment($data['nameDepartment']);
    $department->setCodedepartment($data['codeDepartment']);
    $department->setIdfkgeographicalarea($data['idFkGeographicalArea']);

    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Comment: i have much property it's not exist the function update the doctrine i passed $data contains all property and do update

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: i waste the time to write for all setid setproperty in zend 1 i used $this->update($data,id) i updated all field of the table where id ='$id' so how can i use this update in doctrine if existe in doctrine

Comment: Doctrine does not have anything to do with Zend Framework 2. Those are two separate products. You can read about the Doctrine Hydrator though if you want to hydrate the doctrine entity from array input. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md