# How can i do update ($data,array('id=?'=>$id) in doctrine zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine

How can i do this script the update :

```
$this->update($data, array('id = ?' => $id));
```

in Doctrine and zend Framework 2

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post more code, what type of object is $this, is it your entity?

Comment: i used just that script in zend 1 and i want do the same in doctrine to update table i passed data and id how can i do that ? thanks in advance

Comment: Again, I repeat: what type of object is $this, is it your entity?

Comment: no that the script already used in zend 1 i want do the same in doctrine to do update $this it's used in zend 1

Comment: I already read few of your question and it's always the same, you provide ONE single line of code and you expect us to be magician or hack your local computer to get more code to help you. Please consider some of those comments asking you to provide more code and update your question. Plus, when we answer to you no feedback provided.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this previous question from the same author :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113013/how-can-i-do-update-table-doctrine ; You should know asking a poor quality question twice will not provide better answer than a good quality question

Answer (score 0):

You may use Marco Pivetta tutorial: http://ocramius.github.io/blog/doctrine-2-orm-zf2-tutorial/

after [installation doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) in your zend framework 
you can update like :

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $group = $em
            ->getRepository('App\Domain\Entities\Groups')
            ->findOneBy(['name' => 'partner']);
        $group->setName('Admin');
        $em->merge($group);
        $em->flush();
```

this is  'App\Domain\Entities\Groups' the name of entity which i want to update. with setName I do changes the value of filed that I want to update.

Comment: i found not the tutorial in this link

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: i want do update with doctrine i have $data contains much data and i want passed the data to update my entity thanks in advance @Alireza Rahmani

Comment: @kurchisuiden i have updated the answer check it out i wish this could help you

Comment: i want update entity contains much property each settter it's contains 1000 property i hava data contains all 1000 how can i do update ($data,id)